# Visual Basic issue with "budget" in calculated pivot field

Tags: vba

I'm basic in MS Excel VBA and have an issue with calculated fields in my pivot.

Basically, below statement does not work:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CalculatedFields.Add _
    "Budget vs actual+rem FC YTD", _
    "=BULK QTY Budget Ytd 201408", True
```

When I replace the word "Budget" by "Budgt" (in the script and in the pivot table) it works.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CalculatedFields.Add _
    "Budget vs actual+rem FC YTD", _
    "=BULK QTY Budgt Ytd 201408", True
```

Same if I replace by "Bud get", "Buget" or anything else.

Any suggestions?